# how to remove characters from end of the NSString till "/"

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I have a string like this **`@"Root/dbo-NewsLocation/Item 1/dbo-Relator-test/Item 1/Item 1"`**

When user taps on back button I need to remove @"/Item1" at the end of above string.

I am not able to remove @"Item1" If I do the `stringByReplacingOccuranceOfString` by using below code it remove all @"Item1" using the below code.

```
NSString *str1=self.lblCIPath.text;
        NSRange range = [str1 rangeOfString:@"/" options: NSBackwardsSearch];
        NSString *newString = [str1 substringFromIndex:(range.location)];
        self.lblCIPath.text=[self.lblCIPath.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:newString withString:@""];
```

I will be thankful if anyone can suggest me the way to delete the last `componentPath` from `NSString`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried the method `stringByDeletingLastPathComponent` ?

```
NSString *updatedPath = [myFullPath stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];
```

Answer (score 3):

As Mathieu Meylan suggested you can use `stringByDeletingLastPathComponent`, or you can simply adjust your code to use `substringToIndex` instead of `substrinFromIndex` as follows:

```
NSString *str1=self.lblCIPath.text;
NSRange range = [str1 rangeOfString:@"/" options: NSBackwardsSearch];
NSString *newString = [str1 substringToIndex:(range.location)];
```

Final result will be the same:
`Root/dbo-NewsLocation/Item 1/dbo-Relator-test/Item 1`